# What's the alternative to the reduce pattern with Promises when dealing with recursion?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

*Note: I cannot use `async`.*

I like to use the `reduce` pattern in cases where I need to run over an array and execute the same function on its members and return a promise, like so:

```js
function get_count() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(3);
  });
}

function recursively_execute(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(data);
  });
}

function reduce_promise_pattern() {

  const get_batch_run_count = get_count();

  const batch_process = get_batch_run_count.then((count_value) => {

    const run_count = new Array(count_value).fill('batch');

    function recursive_function(data) {
      console.log('Running batch!');
      return recursively_execute(data).then(() => {
        return data;
      });
    }

    return run_count.reduce((previous_promise) => {
      return previous_promise.then((previous_response) => {
        test_data = {
          'test': 1
        };
        return recursive_function(test_data);
      })
    }, Promise.resolve())
  });
  return batch_process;
}
```

This will run 3 times because of the `run_count` which basically builds an array of 3 items. Although it works, this feels like a hack to me.

This approach works when my list is already pre-defined with unique items and these items, well, individually **are used inside that reduce as data that is built upon** for example, if I have 3 steps to go through, these 3 steps are all unique and each step's data will be used within that one run...but in my case? I'm just tricking the system to think these are different items.

What is the alternative to this?

Comment: The scenario is not entirely clear to me. Do you start with an array of promises or an array of normal values? What is the purpose of using `reduce`? Do you want to wait till all promises are resolved? Because in that case you might as well use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Executing the same function for every element can be achieved with almost all iterating methods, not only `reduce`. `forEach` or `map` would also work, but the choice depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: To further elaborate on the above. I guess a clear example is missing from the snippet. Although your snippet works without a problem it doesn't clarify what you're trying to achieve. Could you add such an example? eg. "I'm getting an array of promises returned from a third party library. I'd like to execute a certain function for each element if the promise resolves."

Comment: @3limin4t0r Forget about the specifics of "why" of this example. The reasoning for my question is "is this right?". If you actually look at the code-base, I'm **unecessarily** building an array filled with the same word by N size, N being the number of times I need that iteration to run for. So I'm wondering if there's a pattern / solution to make this look better.

Answer (score 3):

You reached the limits of Promise chains, although they work they ain't readable. That's why `async` / `await` was introduced to handle exactly these usecases, with them you can just halt all kinds of (nested) loops without having to maintain promises for each:

```
 async function reducePromisePattern() {
   for(let i = await getCount(); i >= 0; i--) {
     await recursiveFunction({'test': 1 });
   }
 }
```

If you can't use / transpile `async`, you could still write some small helpers to do the looping for you, e.g.:

```
 function loopAsync(times, fn) {
   function task() {
    times--;
    if(times <= 0) return;
    return fn().then(task);
   }

   return Promise.resolve().then(task);
 }

 function reducePromisePattern() {
   return getCount().then(function(count) {
      return asyncLoop(count, function() {
         return recursiveFunction({ test: 1 });
      });
   });
 }
```

Comment: I cannot use `async` unfortunately due to the polyfills being really unreliable in my experience. Sorry, if I knew that this could be an answer, I would've added it in the post (I will now).

Comment: You can't polyfill syntax, you can transpile it. Babel does quite a good job with that, never had any problems

Comment: Please refer me to the said package and I'll try to re-write parts of my system with `await` if it passes my tests. I don't know JS at all, so, excuse my wrong usage of terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options without nesting functions in one another. The first one simply uses a for-loop while the second function uses a recursive solution. The last argument of both solutions is optional and should only be used if you want to pass the return data forward from one run to the next (similar to `reduce`).

```js
const sleep = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 1500 + 500));

// solution #1 - for-loop
function times1(n, callback, init) {
  var promise = Promise.resolve(init);
  
  for (; n > 0; --n) {
    promise = promise.then(val => callback(val));
  }
  
  return promise;
}

// example usage
times1(3, n => {
  console.log("solution #1 -", n);
  return sleep().then(() => n + 1);
}, 0);


// solution #2 - recursive
function times2(n, callback, init) {
  var promise = Promise.resolve(init);
  
  if (n <= 0) return promise;
  return promise.then(val => times2(n - 1, callback, callback(val)));
}

// example usage
times2(3, n => {
  console.log("solution #2 -", n);
  return sleep().then(() => n + 1);
}, 0);
```